# Is there a way to restrict the route only within country on Here API?

Tags: here-api

I'm using [Here API Calculate Route](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-a-simple-route.html) to get the route between two locations.
What I need is to restrict the route to be only within some given country (Brazil, in my case).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter to exclude countries. It takes a list of ISO 3166-1-alpha-3 country codes, like that:

```
excludeCountries=BOL,PRY,URY
```

Granted, your question is more the other way around, i.e. how to include only specific countries, but as far as I know there is no such parameter, and I assume you can work around by listing all neighbor countries to the `excludeCountries` parameter.

**Source: [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html)**